# In Java, why is there no instance method like bigDecimal.isGreaterThan(otherBigDecimal)?

Tags: java, api-design, javadocs

The current way of knowing if a BigDecimal is greater than another is

```
bigDecimal.compareTo(otherBigDecimal) > 0
```

(or `one.compareTo(another) == 1`), but I find it too clunky and unexpressive. `bigDecimal.isGreaterThan(otherBigDecimal)` is easier to understand.

For people who are used to Java and know how `compareTo()` works, the present way makes sense. For someone who has OO programming experience other than Java, I assume they would have to look at the API to understand what the magic numbers are for in this operation.

I saw no attempt in Guava or Apache's NumberUtils to fix this and we are already about to reach Java 9.

In gist, what I'm asking is, is there any legitimate reason that this clunky way of comparing BigDecimals has not been redone? (Other than "There's so much to fix in Java, this just is not a priority.")

Answer (score 2):

Aside the actual:

> There's so much to fix in Java, this just is not a priority.

There is another one. If you have a `isGreaterThan`, it means that you will also want to have `isLesserThan`. This would solve *your* needs, but not the needs of the developers who will rather search for `isSuperiorTo` and `isInferiorTo` and be disappointed when auto-completion doesn't show the corresponding method.

More importantly, what do you do with `compareTo`? Do you remove it? If yes, this will break *all* previously written code which uses this method. If you keep it, you now have two redundant methods, and two different ways to perform an action, and you have forum threads where people argue which one of those two approaches is better.

Another approach would be to use an `enum`:

```
bigDecimal.compareTo(otherBigDecimal) == Comparison.firstIsBigger;
```

However, this change is not backwards compatible either.

A very similar issue concerns JUnit-style libraries. There is always a choice between including more and more assertion helpers, or keep the interface light and [let the users ask why their favorite method was not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096650/240613). Basically, a unit testing framework has to include `assert(something)` exclusively. Other helpers can be convenient, but if you try to respond to every need of every user, the framework will end with thousands of methods, and that would be unusable.

Comment: As for removing the method, nobody does that *immediately*, rather `@Deprecate` is used. That would address backwards-compatibility and "arguing" as deprecation sets a clear direction for users of the API.

For your first point: I would rather not dwell on whose needs are met, but on the readability of the code. In that case, `isGreaterThan/isSuperiorTo` are in the same camp where you have an idea what they mean. On the other hand, (to someone whose language background has 0 as false, nonzero as true) `a.compareTo(b) == 1` could mean the objects are equal  and `a.compareTo(b) == 0` unequal.

Comment: @lemuel: `@Deprecate` would better be used exclusively for the cases where the API was clearly wrong or when there is a new way which is undoubtedly better to do a given thing. PHP is a good example of this problem: being poorly designed in the first place, many old functions get deprecated, but years later, people still use them and don't care about deprecation; later, migrating PHP code becomes particularly hard.

Comment: It addresses your question regarding what to do with `compareTo`, which if I understand correctly had the supposition that it is to be replaced by an "undoubtedly better" method, not necessarily `isGreaterThan`. Otherwise, why ask that question?